# Diff: only compare if file exists, not contents

Tags: diff

I want to use Diff only to check if files and directories exist the same in two locations but NOT compare the contents of the files themselves, because that's all I need and a regular Diff just takes too long for the amount of data. How would I go about this? Is there some other Debian standard tool that can accomplish this?

Comment: You mean [like this](http://superuser.com/questions/166317/linux-compare-directory-structure-without-comparing-files)? BTW this is stuff for SuperUser, not ServerFault.

Comment: @Marki Probably more suited for [unix.se] though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use diff for that. Why would your requirement be to use diff? Why do people always come to conclusions without having examined the possible solutions in detail?

You could use `diff -qr` but that wouldn't be wise from a performance point of view if the only goal is to compare the directory structure as outlined [here](https://superuser.com/questions/166317/linux-compare-directory-structure-without-comparing-files)

One of the answers to that question was

```
vimdiff <(cd dir1; find . | sort) <(cd dir2; find . | sort)
```

which

> will give you a nice side-by-side display of the two directory
>   hierarchies with any common sections folded.

Comment: Links are useful for references, but they are no substitute for answering the question. If an answer would not be useful without the links, it is subject to deletion.

Comment: Should be moved to superuser anyway where it can be flagged as duplicate because the answer is there. No need for me to take credit for answers other people gave there.

Comment: No. That a similar question was asked on [su] does not make the question off-topic on [unix.se]. It also doesn't reduce the requirements for an answer to be considered suitable.

Comment: Wow, what a useful command! And kudos for OP for asking - had the exact same question even *after* looking through the manual of diff. Rant could be removed from answer IMO

Comment: As I wrote in my answer. diff is the wrong tool. Why read the manual for diff instead of finding the right tool in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I would have made this a comment on [Marki's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/274179/135943) but it would have been too long.  There is a caveat to his solution:

Parsing output of `ls` or `find` are alike [non-robust and liable to breakage](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/135943).  Here is an example:

```
$ mkdir dir{1,2}
$ touch !$/file{1..5}
touch dir{1,2}/file{1..5}
$ mkdir dir1/$'\n'.
$ touch !$/whoops
touch dir1/$'\n'./whoops
$ touch dir2/whoops
$ touch dir1/onlyin1
$ touch dir2/onlyin2
$ comm <( cd dir1 ; find . | sort ) <( cd dir2 ; find . | sort )
        .
.
./
./
        ./file1
        ./file2
        ./file3
        ./file4
        ./file5
./onlyin1
    ./onlyin2
        ./whoops
```

(I'm using `comm` for three-way text comparison rather than `vimdiff` so I can copy-paste more easily; the result is the same in `vimdiff`.)

You see that this incorrectly displays that the file `whoops` is in both directories, when in fact one of those `whoops` files is in in a subdirectory of `dir1` which contains a newline in its name.

Normally people don't put newlines in filenames or directory names, and the `vimdiff` answer *should* work on any other special characters (though I haven't tested).  However it's still something to be wary of.  If you are going to put this into a script or into production code of any kind, please work on making it more robust, e.g. by walking both directory trees properly and comparing them.